# How to Inset Text/Curve Mesh?

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, geometry, text-object, tools

I am wondering if there is an easy way to inset mesh that is generated from text/curves? When I convert text to mesh it generates a bunch of uneven triangles that don't inset properly. My only solution is slow and tedious and requires manually removing all but the outline edges and refilling with quads.

More specifically I am trying to create an engraving of text into a mesh, and rather than a straight bool cut I need the engraved text to inset a bit. The result needs to mesh (not through a shader). Any ideas appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use "limited Dissolve"

Just select all the vertices, then press <kbd>X</kbd> > Limited Dissolve, after that try the inset again.[image]

Comment: Ah that is much better. It's still not "perfect" but I might just need to play around with the angle limiter and patch a few holes here and there. Thanks, I knew there was some trick I was missing!